# нужно из двух массивов создать один,который не будет включать в себя не уникальные элементы

Tags: javascript, filter, indexof

вместе с гуглом решила вот так.

```
var firstArray = [1,2, 2];
var secondArray = [3,4];
var mergedArray = firstArray.concat(secondArray);
var removeDuplicates = mergedArray.filter(function (elem, index) {
return mergedArray.indexOf(elem) === index})
```

но не могу понять эту строку

```
return mergedArray.indexOf(elem) === index
```

зачем зачем  === index?

Comment: Это строгое сравнение...

Answer (score 0):

Это условие фильтрации.
Так как `mergedArray.indexOf(elem)` вернет первый индекс, то таким образом вы избавитесь от всех дублирующих значений (в данном случае от 2: `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 4]`).

`[1, 2, 2, 3, 4].indexOf(2)` всегда будет возвращать 1 (индекс первого совпадения).

Соответственно `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4].indexOf(2) === 2 // 1 === 2` на третье итерации вернет `false` и это значение не попадет в результирующий массив.